# Log out of google account remotely

Tags: android, google-account

I had logged in to google on an unknown android device, but forgot to log out. I want to log out using my laptop/android device. But I am not able to find any solution on the web. Please let me know how to do that..

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions

Log in to dashboard. And click **Revoke access** button corresponding to the device.

Comment: This answer seems to be outdated, the site doesn't list devices, only connected apps.

Comment: Your device list can now be found here: https://myaccount.google.com/device-activity